# Access a word definition from within an app?

Tags: dictionary, share-menu, copy-paste

Sometimes when I use an app on my Nexus tablet offline, I encounter words for which I would like to quickly check the definition. This is the solution I am currently using

1. select the word
2. copy to clipboard
3. switch to a dictionary app
4. paste the word and read the definition
5. switch back to my original app

I have to do this often, and this is quite inconvenient.
Is there a more direct way to access word definitions when offline?

---

[image: http://imageshack.com/a/img585/3637/epx5.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to invoke dictionary apps like [GoldenDict](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.goldendict.android.free) or [ColorDict](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.socialnmobile.colordict) by "sharing" to them:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think app suggestions are off-topic here.

But you may want to try this [Quick Dictionary](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kkint.dictionary.com) app...